# Modify the XAxis label in ReCharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

I have a Recharts Line graph, and the X-Axis has too many data points, and is looking very congested. Following is the current graph:
[image]

Is there a way that I can rotate this text to lets say 270° so that all the labels would be visible?